# Footer not staying at bottom of page after a form

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with the placement of my footer on my contact page. On every other page of my site the Footer is correctly placed at the bottom of the page, but for some reason the footer is sitting ABOVE my form, even covering the first input box. Can someone please help me?

Here is the coding for my contact form:

```css
 footer {
 display: block;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;      
 width:960px; 
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
    }

    footer .footer-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding:  3px 20px;
    }

    ul#social li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    }

    ul#social li a {
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.facebook, a.twitter {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 24px;
        padding-left: 17px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        width: 16px;
    }
```

```html
 <section>
    <div>
 <form name="customerForm" method="post" action="?">
  <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="width: 95%;" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td>Name: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="cusName" size="25" value="<?php echo $fullName; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Email: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="cusEmail" size="30" value="<?php echo $emailAddress; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Mobile: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="cusMobile" size="25" value="<?php echo $mobilePhone; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Enquiry: </td>
   <td><textarea name="posting" cols="52" rows="25"><?php echo $posting; ?></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />&nbsp;
   <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form"/></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
 
    </div>
    </section>
  <footer>
            <div class="footer-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; My-Com Computers</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <ul id="social">
                        <li><a href="http://facebook.com" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com" class="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you missed table close tag your html `</table>`

```
 <section>
 <div>
 <form name="customerForm" method="post" action="?">
<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="width: 95%;" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cusName" size="25" value="<?php echo $fullName; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cusEmail" size="30" value="<?php echo $emailAddress; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Mobile: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cusMobile" size="25" value="<?php echo $mobilePhone; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Enquiry: </td>
    <td><textarea name="posting" cols="52" rows="25"><?php echo $posting; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form"/></td>
</tr>
</table><!-- new added-->
</form>

</div>
</section>
```

here is your output https://jsfiddle.net/mxmd5jq9/

Comment: So I did. Thank you very much =)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close the table tag

```
<section>
<div>
<form name="customerForm" method="post" action="?">
    <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="width: 95%;" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cusName" size="25" value="<?php echo $fullName; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cusEmail" size="30" value="<?php echo $emailAddress; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mobile: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cusMobile" size="25" value="<?php echo $mobilePhone; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enquiry: </td>
        <td><textarea name="posting" cols="52" rows="25"><?php echo $posting; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello, i  have same answer  putted for this question so  why you not see before you give your answer

Comment: :D i haven't seen your answer bro, is it a problem ?

Comment: Sorry @kebir, but i don't feel good when your finded solution someone give same answer

Comment: @Suresh Suthar we are here for helping not for competition, if you need more score i give you for free, i have more than 10 years experience i don't need this score

Comment: yes you are true, i have no Greed for  score, but sometime when i give answer of some one question. then i gived answer not given by anyone but it exist it in some another question, then i victim for downvote